# Game Center with no publiuc leaderboards and only seeing friends scores

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center

I have finally got game center authenticating and my next step is scores. I have a actual score that can bge easily submitted, porblem is I dont want it going to a public leaderboard. All I want the user to see is thier friends score. Is this possible? I know this is probably in the apple docs, but I have trouble interpreting them. Can I make a leaderboard but not be public? And only pull scores from the friends on the leaderboard? Sorry if this is confusing, I can explain more if u need me too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Game Center leaderboards are all public. Have you considered using a third party API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are being SandBox mode. In sandBox mode, I can only see my own score. I'm looking for its reason. Some guys said it is bug but I'm not sure about that!